# Customize Custom Jquery Plugin With Click Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-plugins

There isn't really a problem, I just know that the way I have my current Jquery plugin working that it is not the most efficient and I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

So, this is the behaviour of the plugin:
1. On click of a link with a certain class (there could be multiple links with the same class), options are passed to the plugin, some are hard coded but some are gathered from data-attributes.
2. A bootstrap modal is shown (blank modal).
3. Ajax post to external page with options from function posted.
5. Ajax success callback puts the new html content into the modal to display.

This is my current jquery plugin

```
(function($){
    $.fn.custom_xedit = function( options ) {

        var settings = $.extend({
        type: this.attr("data-type"),
        selectsource: this.attr("data-selectsource"),
        mask: this.attr("data-mask"),
        title: this.attr("data-title"),
        pk: this.attr("data-pk"),
        posturl: this.attr("data-posturl"),
        originalvalue: this.attr("data-originalvalue"),
        name: this.attr("data-name")
        }, options );

        this.addClass('xedit___el___active');

        $('#xedit_modal').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: { 
                'type': settings.type,
                'selectsource': settings.selectsource,
                'mask': settings.mask,
                'title': settings.title,
                'pk': settings.pk,
                'posturl': settings.posturl,
                'originalvalue': settings.originalvalue,
                'name': settings.name
            },
            success: function(callback_modal){
                $("#xedit_modal").html(callback_modal);
            }
        });
    }; 
}( jQuery ));
```

And I currently call it by:

```
$('body').on("click", ".some_class", function () {
    $(this).custom_xedit({
        type: "input_mask",
        mask: "999",
        title: "Internal extension",
        posturl: "some_url",
        name: "Ext"
    });
});
```

It would be nice to be able to call it without surrounding it with a on click, but not sure how to do that (like below:)

```
$(.some_class).custom_xedit({
type: "input_mask",
mask: "999",
title: "Internal extension",
posturl: "some_url",
name: "Ext"
});
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused, aren't you already wrapping the call in an onclick in the $('body').on('click'....) chunk?

Comment: Yes I am, but I'd like to call the plugin without wrapping it in a click, I'm not sure if it is possible to have the plugin initiate the click event